Flutter: GIF file load slow in Oneplus devices but works fine in others devices
I'm attempting to load a .gif file from the asset folder, but it loads very slowly on OnePlus devices. I've tested it on other devices, and the gif works well on them. I've tried using the precacheImage function, but it didn't work. Is there a better approach for optimising gif loading on OnePlus devices?

What is your approach?

I tried adding this in MyApp build method 'precacheImage(const AssetImage('assets/images/output_gif.gif'), context);'
Then load the gif file via GifView.asset() but i didn't worked.
